# calling __coerce__() method on derived classes results in an error

Tags: python, inheritance, derived-class, coerce

My trial was like below, but it didn't work.

```
class MyNum:
   def __init__(self , n):
   self.n = n

class MyNum2(MyNum):
   def __coerce__(self , y):
        return self, y

   def __radd__(self, y):
        print 'radd called'
        return self.n + y.n
```

I typed on the python command line:

```
>>> x = MyNum(20)
>>> y = MyNum2(12)
>>> x+y
```

Result:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    y+x
  File "", line 3, in __coerce__
    return self.y
AttributeError: MyNum instance has no attribute 'y'
```

When I use the `__coerce__()` method without class deriving, the result of
`x+y` equals to `radd called // 32`. However, with derived-class, an error occurs.

Please give me some help, and happy lunar new year, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, your `__coerce__` implementation actually had

```
return self.y
```

instead of the

```
return self,y
```

as you've written in the example code.

Your code above works for me, and you don't actually even need the `__coerce__` method here. Just having the `__radd__` is sufficient in your example.

Comment: I did those example codes for experiment. It was first time to me to use \__coerce__ method as operator overriding. Anyway, Thank you, shang(^-^) and you're right. The only problem with my code was ',' !!